# vCenter 5.1 -- adding v5.0 host doesn't bring in templates

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, templates

I just set up a vSphere / vCenter 5.1 installation.

I added two older hosts (v5.0) to this installation.

I just noticed that while all VMs have been added to the inventory, none of the templates have.

Is there a reason for this? I can't seem to find anything on the Google or VMWare forums.

Comment: What about contacting VMWare support directly? --afterall you are paying for it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browse to the datastore in which the template is on, find the .vmtx file, right click on it and "add to inventory".

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Didn't realize that these were actually kept along with vCenter Server. A quick browse fixed it!